# Confusion around Forms and Windows Authentication in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication, windows-authentication

So I created an empty MVC project as a learning experience and now I've got some login stuff going, there's another problem...

It seems the thing likes to think I care about using Windows Authentication, so I added the following to my web.config file:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

Now, looking at the _LoginPartial.cshtml file:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated) {
    <text>
        Hello, @Html.ActionLink(User.Identity.Name, "Manage", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "username", title = "Manage" })!
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Logoff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>
        }
    </text>
} else {
    <ul>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
    </ul>
}
```

I'm getting the following error now when I try to run the app:

> Value cannot be null or empty.

This line is highlighted:

```
Hello, @Html.ActionLink(User.Identity.Name, "Manage", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "username", title = "Manage" })!
```

It occurred to me to just remove this, but it also seems to me that even with Forms Authentication, this would be useful, so I've got no idea what to do now.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions on implementing Forms Authentication here.

Comment: The problem here is that you created a project that assumed Windows Authentication, therefore it used templates tailored for that.  You should instead create a new project and make sure you choose a template that uses Forms Authentication.

Comment: Was hoping I wouldn't have to do that, but I did, now its lost <AppName>.Models namespace :/

Comment: Huh?  Namespaces are controllable by you.  You just create you just create models with that namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Use Individual User Accounts. I would recommend you start over rather than trying to modify authentication.

[image]